# How to substitute part of a string from one list with another part from another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way that allows me to substitute part of a string from one list with another part from another list based on some condition (copy-paste) without affecting the rest of it. I have two lists

```py
correct_format = ['BWx0520BG6,2x','CBZ3132Bu1,3','CKZ3134BR4,2','SJD8575RZ4,2','UES9151GS5,2']
wrong_format = ['BWL0520BG6,1','CBZ3132BR1,2c','CKZ313\\BR4,1','SJD8|75RZ4,1','UES915*GS5,1']
```

I want to compare between correct_format and wrong_format list, based on a condtiotion if true part of the wrong format will be substituted with part of the correct_format value so `'BWL0520BG6,1'` should become `'BWx0520BG6,1'` only `BWL0520BG6` should be changed. the `1` in `'BWL0520BG6,1'` should be excluded. `'CBZ3132BR1,2c'` should become `'CBZ3132Bu1,2c'` only `CBZ3132BR1` should be changed. the `2c` in `'CBZ3132BR1,2c'` should be excluded. and this should be applied to the rest.

This what I have done so far

```py
corrected = []
correct_format = ['BWx0520BG6,2x','CBZ3132Bu1,3','CKZ3134BR4,2','SJD8575RZ4,2','UES9151GS5,2']
wrong_format = ['BWL0520BG6,1','CBZ3132BR1,2c','CKZ313\\BR4,1','SJD8|75RZ4,1','UES915*GS5,1']

def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))

for r in correct_format:
    for i in wrong_format:
        li_r = r.split(',')
        li_i = i.split(',')
        if  hamming_distance(li_r[0], li_i[0]) == 1:
            corrected.append(r)
            wrong_format.remove(i)
```

but it seems not working properly, instead of copying part of the string it copies all of the string which results into incorrect results

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `enumerate` and a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
correct_format = ['BWx0520BG6,2x','CBZ3132Bu1,3','CKZ3134BR4,2','SJD8575RZ4,2','UES9151GS5,2']
wrong_format = ['BWL0520BG6,1','CBZ3132BR1,2c','CKZ313\\BR4,1','SJD8|75RZ4,1','UES915*GS5,1']

for ind, v in enumerate(correct_format):
    val = wrong_format[ind].split(",") 
    val[0] = v.split(",")[0]
    wrong_format[ind] = ",".join(val)

print(wrong_format)
```

**Output:**

```
['BWx0520BG6,1',
 'CBZ3132Bu1,2c',
 'CKZ3134BR4,1',
 'SJD8575RZ4,1',
 'UES9151GS5,1']
```

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh very much. what if my string looks like this `'SJD8775RZ4,HZT2506M,IAH,LMS,1420564324,1044\n',`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: lets say this is the correct_format =  `'SJD8775RZ4,HZT2506M,IAH,LMS,1420564324,1044\n'` and this is wrong_format = `'SJD8775RZ9,XOY7948U,LHR,MIA,100000,1000\n'` and the expected output is `'SJD8775RZ4,XOY7948U,LHR,MIA,100000,1000\n'`

Comment: so we need to work on the first 10 characters where there is only one character different

Comment: Thanks very much, it works.  what about if I want to insert the updated results in a third list?